# Overlap ::after and ::before with text in CSS

Tags: html, css

**Goal:** Make nice effect of hovering buttons in pure CSS, which will use `::after` and `::before` pseudo-elements. Look at this **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LL0f7rwp/)** example to see, what I want to reach.

**Code:** Button will have some styling, also an `background-color`, which is turned off in this example.

```
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

**Problem:** I want to use `background-color` and when I enable it, then I can't see pseudo-elements. It is like that, because these pseudo-elements have `z-index: -1;`, which put them behind the background. When I change `z-index` to `0` or `1`, then text is not visible.

**What I can't do:** I can't add new elements inside buttons (like `span`s), because this is one already running website and client decided to change the behavior of buttons, so here I am. There are tons of buttons in this website, so this is the reason, why I want to find solution with pseudo-elements, because trying to find every single button and change them would be inappropriate.

Comment: maybe a simple [z-index](https://jsfiddle.net/pwvuytvg/) stuff?

Comment: @RemusGLS ohh, `z-index` on the main element... Why didn't I try this? Thanks a lot, this one fixed it all.

Comment: it happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood you well, this is what you are looking for:

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    /*background-color: white;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
 border:1px solid;
}
a.button:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    height: 0%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #ddd;
 transition: height 0.2s ease;
}

a.button:hover:before {
 height:100%;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">TEST</a>
```

Comment: All it needed was to add `z-index: 1;` to the button, so then it is good. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes `z-index` was what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Consider an alternative method of doing the background colour transition thing.

As seen [in this edited demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LL0f7rwp/2/):

```
/* remove all references to .button::before */
.button {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
        transparent, transparent 100%,
        red 100%, red);
    transition: background-image 0.5s ease 0s;
}
/* the "gradient" above has the practical result of being fully transparent,
   but it has been carefully crafted so that the transition gives the desired result */
.button:hover {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,
        transparent, transparent 0%,
        red 0%, red);
}
```

You can transition gadients, and in this case it is done stop-by-stop. The first and last stops don't change, but the middle two transition from `100%` to `0%`, essentially meaning that the cut-off point between `transparent` and `red` slides from the bottom to the top of the button, giving the effect you want.

You can now replace `transparent` with your desired background colour.

* You may need to remove the `z-index:-1` from the `::after` element to get the border effect back.

Comment: Thanks, it is good point, but I accepted @divy3993's answer, because he has transition.

Comment: @debute Erm... mine has transition too...?

Comment: Sorry, now I see in the code, but it is not animating in my browser, chromium 45.8.12.389 - I don't know why.

Comment: Ah. See, the specification says it should work, and it does work in Internet Explorer (and Edge), but apparently Chrome/Chromium still sucks.

Comment: First time I see something working in IE and not in Chrome.

Comment: Edge is based on Chromium now so now they both suck. Progress.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like,

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="button"></a>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #FF7272;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    z-index: 0;
    background-color: white;
    width: 50px;
}
.button::before, .button::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.button::after {
    content: "TEST";
    height: 50%;
    width: 72px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
    line-height: 0.2;
    border-left: 4px solid red;
    border-right: 4px solid red;
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
.button::before {
    height: 0%;
    background-color: red;
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
    z-index: 1;
}
.button:hover::before {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/LL0f7rwp/6/

*Some values are hard coded, but hope you can get an idea out of it* :)

Comment: Thanks, but I already find a solution also with half-borders.

Comment: @debute: Oh ok cool, I also updated my solution with half bordered. Check my solution as well, if does what you expected. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's because `z-index: -1` and `background-color: white` will push your `:before` and `:after` elements beneath.

1. Remove `z-index: -1` from `:after` and `:before` and add to hover `.button:hover::before`
2. Make the `background-color: transparent` while hovering. [Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/LL0f7rwp/5/)

```css
body {
  background: #FF7272;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
.button::before,
.button::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.button::after {
  height: 50%;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-top: 0;
}
.button::before {
  height: 0%;
  background-color: red;
  transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
}
.button:hover::before {
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">TEST</a>
```

Comment: The text inside of button is invisible.

Comment: That white background become transparent on hover :( See comment on my question where is solution.